# UI plot position in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

The code below is a follow-up example of [pyqtgraph](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/Plotting.py).

What I have added is imported txt data and plotted a 2D graph. The problem I'm having is the plot 1 is generated separately. I have replaced one of the plots named `p1` from the example. What is happening now the plot is generated separated from the UI. See the below output:

[image]

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import initExample ## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)


    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
This example demonstrates many of the 2D plotting capabilities
in pyqtgraph. All of the plots may be panned/scaled by dragging with
the left/right mouse buttons. Right click on any plot to show a context menu.
"""

import initExample ## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)


from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
import csv
#QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem('raster')
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
#mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
#mw.resize(800,800)

win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
#win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="Basic plotting examples")
win.resize(1000,600)
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')
win.show()
# Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

p1 = win.addPlot(title="Multiple curves")
x = []
y = []
with open('example.txt','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))
arrX = np.array(x)
arrY = np.array(y)
yerr = np.sqrt(arrY)*0.1
p1 = pg.plot()
err=pg.ErrorBarItem(x=arrX, y=arrY, top=yerr, bottom=yerr,left=0, right=0, beam=0.0)
p1.addItem(err)
p1.plot(x, y, symbol='o', pen={'color': 0.8, 'width': 2})

p2 = win.addPlot(title="Multiple curves")
p2.plot(np.random.normal(size=100), pen=(255,0,0), name="Red curve")
p2.plot(np.random.normal(size=110)+5, pen=(0,255,0), name="Green curve")
p2.plot(np.random.normal(size=120)+10, pen=(0,0,255), name="Blue curve")

p3 = win.addPlot(title="Drawing with points")
p3.plot(np.random.normal(size=100), pen=(200,200,200), symbolBrush=(255,0,0), symbolPen='w')


win.nextRow()

p4 = win.addPlot(title="Parametric, grid enabled")
x = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000))
y = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 1000))
p4.plot(x, y)
p4.showGrid(x=True, y=True)

p5 = win.addPlot(title="Scatter plot, axis labels, log scale")
x = np.random.normal(size=1000) * 1e-5
y = x*1000 + 0.005 * np.random.normal(size=1000)
y -= y.min()-1.0
mask = x > 1e-15
x = x[mask]
y = y[mask]
p5.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol='t', symbolPen=None, symbolSize=10, symbolBrush=(100, 100, 255, 50))
p5.setLabel('left', "Y Axis", units='A')
p5.setLabel('bottom', "Y Axis", units='s')
p5.setLogMode(x=True, y=False)

p6 = win.addPlot(title="Updating plot")
curve = p6.plot(pen='y')
data = np.random.normal(size=(100,1000))
ptr = 0
def update():
    global curve, data, ptr, p6
    curve.setData(data[ptr%10])
    if ptr == 0:
        p6.enableAutoRange('xy', False)  ## stop auto-scaling after the first data set is plotted
    ptr += 1
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(50)


win.nextRow()

p7 = win.addPlot(title="Filled plot, axis disabled")
y = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)) + np.random.normal(size=1000, scale=0.1)
p7.plot(y, fillLevel=-0.3, brush=(50,50,200,100))
p7.showAxis('bottom', False)


x2 = np.linspace(-100, 100, 1000)
data2 = np.sin(x2) / x2
p8 = win.addPlot(title="Region Selection")
p8.plot(data2, pen=(255,255,255,200))
lr = pg.LinearRegionItem([400,700])
lr.setZValue(-10)
p8.addItem(lr)

p9 = win.addPlot(title="Zoom on selected region")
p9.plot(data2)
def updatePlot():
    p9.setXRange(*lr.getRegion(), padding=0)
def updateRegion():
    lr.setRegion(p9.getViewBox().viewRange()[0])
lr.sigRegionChanged.connect(updatePlot)
p9.sigXRangeChanged.connect(updateRegion)
updatePlot()

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

The txt file is: `example.txt`

```
1,5
2,3
3,4
4,7
5,4
6,3
7,5
8,7
9,4
10,4
```

Comment: Clean up the code. p1 = win.addPlot(title="Multiple curves") and then doing p1 = pg.plot() after a few lines makes no sense at all.

Comment: The next few lines that I intended to do is to make NumPy array and plot the error bar using `ErrorBarItem ` function.  `p1.addItem(err)` should add the pq plot to the UI as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is quite straightforward, add plot and add item to plot:

```
p1 = win.addPlot(title="Error Bar")
arrX = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
arrY = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
yerr = np.sqrt(arrY)*0.1
err = pg.ErrorBarItem(x=arrX, y=arrY, top=yerr, bottom=yerr,left=0, right=0, beam=0.0)
p1.addItem(err)
```